# How to hanlde large files in git without using Git LFS

Tags: git

Can any one provide me information, how  exactly Organisation has utilised GIT to handle large files before existence of GIT LFS feature.

I have requirement to handle large file in git without using git lfs. so, Is there 
any approach for my requirement?

Comment: I am asking for any third party application which can support git binary files. as git can handle only 100 MB capacity. I found some third party like git-annex , git bigfiles, git fat which is best to Implement.

Answer (score 0):

Git has no problem handling large files. It will have more problem handling large binary files.

Anyway, everything will work perfectly fine. It will just be very slow, CPU and bandwith consuming.